# Phusion Passenger issue with running daemon_controller for delayed_job?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, delayed-job

When passenger starts my web app `Process.spawn` in the daemon_controller throws a `ArgumentError` exception with the message `wrong exec option`.

When I run `rails console production` on my server this same piece of code gets hit, but runs fine and then I can access my app from the web.

With a bit of debugging I found that when `rails console production` is calling Process.spawn it is passed:

```
Process.spawn("export RAILS_ENV=production; script/delayed_job restart",
              {#<IO:<STDIN>> => "/dev/null",
               #<IO:<STDOUT>> => "/tmp/daemon-output20110210-15497-20fi88", 
               #<IO:<STDERR>> => "/tmp/daemon-output20110210-15497-20fi88",
               :close_others=>true}
```

To cause Passenger to call this code I run a `touch tmp/restart.txt` and then access my app from the web. When Passenger is calling Process.spawn it is passed:

```
Process.spawn("export RAILS_ENV=production; script/delayed_job restart",
              {#<IO:<STDIN>> => "/dev/null",
               #<IO:<STDOUT>> => "/tmp/daemon-output20110210-15016-kiik39",
               #<PhusionPassenger::Utils::PseudoIO:0x8aaa5ac @sink=#<IO:<STDERR>>, @buffer=#<StringIO:0x8aaa598>> => "/tmp/daemon-output20110210-15016-kiik39",
               :close_others=>true}
```

Process.spawn does not seem to like this PseudoIO object and throws `ArgumentError` exception with the message `wrong exec option`.

For gems I am using:
`rails            3.0.3`
`passenger        3.0.2`
`demon_controller 0.2.5`

Any thoughts on on how to get daemon_controller to work with Passenger would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
Process.spawn(..., STDERR => ...)
```

call

```
Process.spawn(..., :err => ...)
```

Comment: The daemon_controller still craps out trying to start this process. The solution that I am going with is to not use daemon_controller and instead just start the needed processes in a cap script.

Comment: Fixed in daemon_controller 0.2.6.

Comment: Thanks! I will upgrade and check it out.